# A Robust Try Catch Method to use in WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

A Robust Try Catch Method to use in WebDriver?

1. Can someone advice from there experiece whether the following method looks correct in the likely scenario where searching for an element gets timed out or the incorrect locator has been used?
2. The timeout Exception dosnt seem to be printing my System.out.println after i set the wait to 2seconds and change the locator with the wrong xpath

**My Code:**

```
    public void clickSupercarsLink() throws Exception {
    try {
        this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(link_Supercars)).click();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        System.out.println("UNABLE TO FIND ELEMENT : Timeout");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("UNABLE TO FIND ELEMENT : Exception");
        throw (e);
    }
}
```

**New Code:**

```
public void clickSupercarsLink() throws Exception {
    try {
        this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(link_Supercars)).click();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        System.out.println("Timed out attempting to click on element: <" + link_Supercars.toString() + ">");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to click on element: " + "<" + link_Supercars.toString() + ">");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you intend not to rethrow in the `TimeoutException` case?

Comment: @Andy Turner what would you advice? if i rethrow the exception what would this do (Sorry if sounds stupid)

Comment: No idea, I don't know what you're trying to do. I'm just pointing out that the method will return normally in the case of a `TimeoutException`, even though the link has not been clicked.

Comment: "if i rethrow the exception what would this do" If you don't know what it's doing, why do you do it in the `catch Exception` branch?

Comment: ok @Andy Turner what im trying to do is 1. click on the element, if its a timeout / or stale element issue make sure the user is aware, if anything else still catch the type of exception and output all exception to the console window, thansk again for your help

Comment: @Phil_P85 so, you want to distinguish between TmeoutException and other exceptions, which is ok. But what is the problem? What do you expect the code to do and what did it? You wrote: _timeout Exception dosnt seem to be printing ..._ Well, what does it print? Maybe, another Exception was thrown. We never know without stack trace or at least error message.

Comment: @Phil_P85 Generally if you are using any framework, then it should handle all the exceptions and report the same to you. Moreover, if you wish to catch exceptions then it should be the exact specific type.

Comment: @Würgspaß thanks how would you handle stale exceptions, or attempt a reclick with the following method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Phil I would want you to throw that exception and handle it at high level. In current scenario, if there is a critical exception, your test will method calling your method `clickSupercarsLink` will not know that there was an exception.

Any way you are throwing exception, why do you have to catch it and do nothing with it then just printing!! This is not why you throw exception right?

```
public void clickSupercarsLink() throws Exception {
this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(link_Supercars)).click();
}
```

Comment: ok @Mayur Shah what changes would you make to the above, based on your experience, sorry finding exception handling a little tricky, thanks again

Comment: This is the best you can do.